# How can Observable get data of Array ? Angular 6

Tags: arrays, typescript, observable, angular6

How can Observable get data of Array ? Angular 6

```
ob: Observable<any>
array= ['a','b','c']
this.ob = array;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to put data into the Observable stream.

```
ob = new Observable<any>(observer=>observer.next(array));
```

Comment: [ts] Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.

Comment: please see revised answer